# Java IndexOf not finding right data

Tags: java, parsing, indexof

I have a java application that needs to parse HTML elements from an HTML page. My simple HTML test is setup as such:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
  div {width:100%;height:100px;background-color:blue;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My code will be setup such that it will search the document for this string: 
    "<style"

And then search for the closing carot: ">" because the user may have typed any of these combinations for their HTML file:

```
<style type="text/css">

or

<style type = "text/css" >

or

<style type = 'text/css' >

or 

<style type='text/css'>

etc..
```

So my method is to find the "style" tag and everything up to its closing carot

Then find the closing style tag:

```
</style>
```

Then grab everything between those two entities.

Here's my files with their code:

```
************strings.xml************

String txt_style_opentag = "<style"
String txt_end_carrot = ">"
String txt_style_closetag = "</style>"

***********************************





************Parser.java************
public static String getStyle(Context context, String text) {
    String style = "";

    String openTag = context.getString(R.string.txt_style_opentag);
    String closeTag = context.getString(R.string.txt_style_closetag);
    String endCarrot = context.getString(R.string.txt_end_carrot);

    int openPos1 = text.indexOf(openTag);
    int openPos = text.indexOf(endCarrot, openPos1);
    int closePos = text.indexOf(closeTag, openPos1);

    if (openPos != -1 && closePos != -1)
        style = text.substring(openPos + openTag.length(), closePos).trim();

    if (style != null && style.length() > 0 && style.charAt(0) == '\n')     // first \n remove
        style = style.substring(1, style.length());

    if (style != null && style.length() > 0 && style.charAt(style.length() - 1) == '\n')    // last \n remove
        style = style.substring(0, style.length() - 1);

    return style;
}
********************************************************
```

My result is close, but not right. The result is this:

```
{width:100%;height:100px;background-color:blue;}
```

If you notice, it is missing the "div" part. It should look like this:

```
div {width:100%;height:100px;background-color:blue;}
```

What am I doing wrong here. Can anyone help?

Comment: As a side note, you may benefit from a library such as jsoup to do your html parsing for you

Comment: I take that back... see below.

Comment: The word is caret, not a carot ... or carrot ... or any other kind of vegetable.  And on top of that `>` is not a caret anyway.  It is a "greater than sign" or (if you want) "right angle-bracket"

Comment: I suppose you don't use the 'string bean' either -->  (

Comment: @Sean do you know if jsoup will work in Android applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're taking the substring from the end of your opening tag (the closing bracket `>`) and adding the length of the opening tag (rather than `endCarrot`), thus moving the start of the substring ahead of where you want it to be. You want to do

```
style = text.substring(openPos + endCarrot.length(), closePos).trim();
```

Comment: I'll still give it to ya ;)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer posted as I was typing mine.

Answer (score 0):

Of course...right after I ask for help I finally figure it out. The following code should be changed

FROM:

```
style = text.substring(openPos + openTag.length(), closePos).trim();
```

TO:

```
style = text.substring(openPos + endCarrot.length(), closePos).trim();
```

Sorry for the post. And thanks for the recommendations